# Reversing or reverse iterating an unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I'm trying to print the contents of an unordered_map in reverse order, but 
it doesn't have rbegin or rend, so you can't use reverse_iterator. How is reversing of the unordered_map supposed to be done?

**EDIT (from comment):** I want the keys to be in the order they were inserted in, hence I cant use map. The keys appear to stay in the insertion order, but I need them reversed.

Comment: The whole point of using an unordered map is that it's unordered... Perhaps `std::map` would be a better fit.

Comment: I am curious: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I want the keys to be in the order they were inserted in, hence I cant use map. The keys appear to stay in the insertion order, but I need them reversed.

Comment: @user1866033: But the keys in unordered map are **not** in order they were inserted. They are in **ARBITRARY** order. Reversing arbitrary order gives you another equally arbitrary order and is therefore pointless.

Comment: reverse iteration based on what? an `unordered_map` is not ordered!

Comment: user1866033, the fact that they are in the same order you inseted them is due to a chance alone. `unordered_map` is not guaranteed to be in any order

Comment: Oh, please, make that comment an edit of the question instead. Than it will make sense and somebody could sensibly answer it.

Comment: Are you saying you want a key-value container with fast lookups, but that also maintains the input order? I'm not sure you can get that easily with the standard containers.

Comment: If you want a collection that keeps order and allows fast lookup by key at the same time, you'll have to use [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/). Standard library does not have one.

Comment: So there is no data structure to use with key-value in insertion order?

Comment: You can use Boost.MultiIndex - one key would be the one you're currently using, the other key would be sequentially assigned integers.

Comment: @user1866033: what operations you want to do on it, except insertion that preserves the order? As it currently stands an `std::vector<pair<Key,Value>>` with `push_back` fits your needs. Give more info.

Comment: @user1866033, you want Boost.MultiIndex. Or if boost if not an option, use two containers: `vector` for storage and `map` or `unordered_map` for lookup by key.

Comment: Is there a way to use something like "find" with the vector pair? I believe this might be what I actually need...I need to do lot of searches, but I don't want it to be too resource-consuming.

Comment: @user1866033: There is a way, but if you say there will be many searches then you are better to use Boost.MultiIndex or use *two* containers simultaneously as people here described.

Comment: @chill: Sequentially assigned integers are not needed. Boost.MultiIndex has option for sequential access (like list) and random access (like vector).

Answer (score 11):

Just reading the first sentence in your question gives you the answer:

> I'm trying to print the contents of an `unordered_map` in reverse
>   order

You cannot print in any order because, well, it is unordered. It makes no sense talking about order in an unordered structure. It does not matter how the contents of an `unordered_map` are organised internally: this is an implementation detail and you cannot access it. To the outside world, an `unordered_map` exhibits no order at all and you cannot expect it to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can cobble up your own pair of reverse iterators from any pair of bidirectional iterators:

```
std::reverse_iterator rbegin(first);
std::reverse_iterator rend(last);
```

As @Tin suggested, this doesn't work. Never mind.

Comment: could you please expand your answer and provide a full example? I'm facing the same issues and tried to follow your suggestion, but got some compiler errors.

Comment: @Tin -- whoops, that doesn't work. An `unordered_map` is only required to support forward iterators; to create a reverse iterator you have to have a bidirectional iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the content of your unordered map into another unoredered map. Do remember inserting using make_pair in a pair form so as to retain your data.

Answer (score 0):

When you use an unordered_map no particular order is going to be maintained because the key values will have an implementation based hash code.

As you mention that you need them in the order you insert -- most probably you will be iterating through some kind of a linear list and storing key values pair in the unordered map. Instead use an ordered_map and insert based on indices of the list. In this case, your order will be maintained as your inserting into the map based on index as key.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this type of thing can be used when you are given some input in form of key-value pairs and you need to do some operation on that and print some result in order of the input received.

So you can use an unordered map.

As said in above posts, unordered map is completely unordered, so a good way of doing this is to have a vector to have your keys and then having all key-value pairs in an unordered map. Then using key values in vector first to find the values in map using find() and then an iterator printing key-value pairs.

See the below example:

Suppose you want to take two integers as an input in form of key-value pair and for purpose of doing some operations on it, you use an unordered map, and now you want to print values in the order of input.

```
vector<int> v;
unordered_map<int,int> m;
unordered_map<int,int>::iterator it;
```

Now when you want to print output in order of input.

```
for (int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
        it=m.find(v[i]);
        if(it!=m.end())
            cout << it->first << " " << it-second << "\n";
}
```

This will print your key-value pairs in the order of the input.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

had the same issue, unordered_map stores data in reverse order

so

```
map[A]=X
map[B]=Y
map[C]=Z
```

if you iterate for(map:iterator it=begin...) you'll get

```
Z
Y
X
```

so it implies an order, witch is reversed

Comment: The order in which an `unordered_map<>::iterator` iterates the entries is entirely up to the implementation. It may be in the order of insertion, it may be in reverse order, or it may be in a pseudo-random order (`unordered_map<>` should be implemented as a hash table, after all), or it may be any cross of these, it may even change behavior with size. So, asserting that it uses reverse order is plain wrong, it's implementation defined order, end of the story.