# Why "unordered_map::iterator" does not provide "operator--"?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, iterator, unordered-map

In traditiona map we can create code like [this](http://ideone.com/oKdUVB):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<int, int> m;
    m[666]=222;
    m[777]=333;
    auto it = --(m.end());
    cout << (*it).first;
    return 0;
}
```

to move backward if needed. Yet in unordered_map for nearly same code we get a compile time error, [observe](http://ideone.com/KJuqeF):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unordered_map<int, int> m;
    m[666]=222;
    m[777]=111;
    auto it = --(m.end());
    cout << (*it).first;
    return 0;
}

prog.cpp:9:12: error: no match for 'operator--' (operand type is 'std::unordered_map<int, int>::iterator {aka std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const int, int>, false, false>}')
  auto it = --(m.end());
            ^
```

Is it such difference standart-defined (and thus explained somewhere) or a compiler bug?

Comment: By the way, I don't think this usage of `--` is good. Why not just `auto it = m.end() - 1;`?

Comment: `unordered_map` is unordered, so reversing it may not make sense. [c++ - Reversing or reverse iterating an unordered_map - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643815/reversing-or-reverse-iterating-an-unordered-map)

Comment: Because it's a forward iterator?

Answer (score 0):

[`map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) and [`ordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) have different iterator requirements (emphasis mine):

> `map`
> `iterator`    a **bidirectional** iterator to `value_type`
>
> `unordered_map`
> `iterator`    a **forward** iterator to `value_type`

Comment: Yes, but _why_?  (I know why, but the answer should tell the OP)

Comment: @MooingDuck If you know, why not write your own answer?

Comment: @MooingDuck I answered the question "_Is it such difference standard-defined_". Regarding "_Why_", I do not know for sure, but what said e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2998664) sounds logical.

Comment: I guess the reason is to allow to implement buckets data in a list-like manner (using either indexes or pointers). It might be beneficial in some situations, e.g., we use such an implementation in a multi-threaded hash table, where inserts use locks, but lookups does not need to (need just one atomic read).